# Interactive WebGL background with svg image layered ontop

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, webgl

I am trying to make a background WebGL page that depending on where the mouse is,  changes the perspective of an image. Layered ontop is a SVG image which has many shapes. The problem is, is that the SVG has an invisible canvas (artboard?) which causes the background WebGL to stop interacting with the mouse.

My question: How can I have it so when the mouse is over both the Background WebGL and the SVG the mouse interacts with both 'layers'? In other words I want the mouse to interact with multible layers.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the mouse position coordinates on the top SVG 'layer' and store them as a global variable which you can use to make the adjustments on both layers.

If you don't need to directly interact with the SVG layer and your mouse then just use `pointer-events:none` on your whole SVG 'layer' - That would cause all mouse interaction to fall-through to the bottom WebGL layer.